# Unable to install Wine on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, wine

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04:
When I try to install wine, it wants to remove lots of packages. (The list is far too long. Not just one or two packages.)
What do you recommend?

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 again.
I have followed [these instructions](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr)

Now I have a feeling that some of the following packages is preventing wine to be installed, but I don't know which one:

```
$ sudo apt-get install synaptic vlc gimp gimp-data gimp-plugin-registry \
gimp-data-extras y-ppa-manager bleachbit oracle-java8-installer flashplugin-installer \
unace unrar zip unzip p7zip-full p7zip-rar sharutils rar uudeview mpack arj cabextract \
file-roller libxine1-ffmpeg mencoder flac faac faad sox ffmpeg2theora libmpeg2-4 \
uudeview libmpeg3-1 mpeg3-utils mpegdemux liba52-dev mpeg2dec vorbis-tools id3v2 \
mpg321 mpg123 libflac++6 totem-mozilla icedax lame libmad0 libjpeg-progs libdvdcss2 \
libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 libswscale-extra-2 ubuntu-restricted-extras smplayer gnome-subtitles \
audacity hunspell-hu
```

I have tried everything explained here, but apparaently thereÍs nothing wrong with the PPAs.

I have tried to install it using aptitude. This is the output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr{a} fonts-horai-umefont{a} fonts-unfonts-core{a} 
  fonts-wqy-microhei{a} gcc-4.8-base:i386{a} gcc-4.9-base:i386{a} 
  libaio1{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libasound2:i386{a} 
  libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} 
  libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libc6:i386{a} 
  libcapi20-3{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcgmanager0:i386{ab} 
  libcomerr2:i386{a} libcups2:i386{ab} libdb5.3:i386{a} 
  libdbus-1-3:i386{ab} libdrm-intel1:i386{a} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{a} 
  libdrm-radeon1:i386{a} libdrm2:i386{a} libelf1:i386{ab} libexif12:i386{a} 
  libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} 
  libfontconfig1:i386{ab} libfreetype6:i386{ab} libgcc1:i386{a} 
  libgcrypt11:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} libgif4:i386{a} 
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{ab} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{ab} libglapi-mesa:i386{ab} 
  libglib2.0-0:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgnutls26:i386{ab} 
  libgpg-error0:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{ab} libgphoto2-port10:i386{ab} 
  libgpm2:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386{a} libgstreamer0.10-0:i386{a} 
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} libhdb9-heimdal{a} 
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libice6:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} 
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{ab} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} 
  libjpeg8:i386{a} libjson-c2:i386{ab} libk5crypto3:i386{a} 
  libkdc2-heimdal{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libkrb5-3:i386{a} libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} 
  libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libllvm3.4:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a} 
  liblzma5:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libncurses5:i386{a} 
  libnih-dbus1:i386{a} libnih1:i386{a} libodbc1{a} libogg0:i386{a} 
  libopenal1:i386{a} liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libosmesa6{ab} libosmesa6:i386{a} 
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} 
  libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpcre3:i386{a} libpng12-0:i386{a} 
  libpulse0:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} libsamplerate0:i386{a} 
  libsane:i386{ab} libsane-common:i386{ab} libsasl2-2:i386{a} 
  libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libselinux1:i386{ab} 
  libsm6:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libspeexdsp1:i386{a} 
  libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssl1.0.0:i386{ab} libstdc++6:i386{a} 
  libtasn1-6:i386{ab} libtiff5:i386{ab} libtinfo5:i386{a} 
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386{a} libudev1:i386{ab} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libuuid1:i386{ab} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} 
  libvorbis0a:i386{a} libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libvpx1:i386{a} 
  libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libx11-6:i386{a} 
  libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libxau6:i386{a} libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} 
  libxcb-dri3-0:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} libxcb-present0:i386{a} 
  libxcb-sync1:i386{a} libxcb1:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} 
  libxcursor1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} libxdmcp6:i386{a} 
  libxext6:i386{a} libxfixes3:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} 
  libxml2:i386{ab} libxpm4:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} libxrender1:i386{a} 
  libxshmfence1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxt6:i386{a} 
  libxxf86vm1:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} 
  p11-kit-modules:i386{a} p7zip{a} python-dnspython{a} samba{ab} 
  samba-dsdb-modules{ab} samba-vfs-modules{ab} tdb-tools{a} 
  ttf-wqy-microhei{a} unixodbc{a} winbind{ab} wine wine-gecko2.21{a} 
  wine-gecko2.21:i386{a} wine-mono0.0.8{a} wine1.6{a} wine1.6-amd64{a} 
  wine1.6-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} zlib1g:i386{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 164 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 181 MB of archives. After unpacking 626 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl1.0.0 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0:i386 (!= 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.4) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libssl1.0.0:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0 (!= 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.4 is installed.
 libsane-common : Conflicts: libsane-common:i386 but 1.0.23-3ubuntu3 is to be installed.
 libsane-common:i386 : Conflicts: libsane-common but 1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1 is installed.
 winbind : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is installed.
           Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1) but 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 is to be installed.
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1 is installed.
 libfontconfig1 : Breaks: libfontconfig1:i386 (!= 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) but 2.11.0-0ubuntu4 is to be installed.
 libfontconfig1:i386 : Depends: fontconfig-config:i386 (= 2.11.0-0ubuntu4) which is a virtual package.
                       Breaks: libfontconfig1 (!= 2.11.0-0ubuntu4) but 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1 is installed.
 libcups2 : Breaks: libcups2:i386 (!= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.1) but 1.7.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed.
 libcups2:i386 : Breaks: libcups2 (!= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1) but 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.1 is installed.
 libtiff5 : Breaks: libtiff5:i386 (!= 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1) but 4.0.3-7 is to be installed.
 libtiff5:i386 : Breaks: libtiff5 (!= 4.0.3-7) but 4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1 is installed.
 libselinux1 : Breaks: libselinux1:i386 (!= 2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1) but 2.2.2-1 is to be installed.
 libselinux1:i386 : Breaks: libselinux1 (!= 2.2.2-1) but 2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1 is installed.
 libjson-c2 : Breaks: libjson-c2:i386 (!= 0.11-3ubuntu1.2) but 0.11-3ubuntu1 is to be installed.
 libjson-c2:i386 : Breaks: libjson-c2 (!= 0.11-3ubuntu1) but 0.11-3ubuntu1.2 is installed.
 samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is installed.
         Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is installed.
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is installed.
 libfreetype6 : Breaks: libfreetype6:i386 (!= 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libfreetype6:i386 : Breaks: libfreetype6 (!= 2.5.2-1ubuntu2) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.2 is installed.
 libcgmanager0 : Breaks: libcgmanager0:i386 (!= 0.24-0ubuntu7) but 0.24-0ubuntu5 is to be installed.
 libcgmanager0:i386 : Breaks: libcgmanager0 (!= 0.24-0ubuntu5) but 0.24-0ubuntu7 is installed.
 libglapi-mesa : Breaks: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1) but 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 is to be installed.
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Breaks: libglapi-mesa (!= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1 is installed.
 libuuid1 : Breaks: libuuid1:i386 (!= 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.1) but 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20 is to be installed.
 libuuid1:i386 : Breaks: libuuid1 (!= 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20) but 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.1 is installed.
 libdbus-1-3 : Breaks: libdbus-1-3:i386 (!= 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.1) but 1.6.18-0ubuntu4 is to be installed.
 libdbus-1-3:i386 : Breaks: libdbus-1-3 (!= 1.6.18-0ubuntu4) but 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.1 is installed.
 samba-dsdb-modules : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is installed.
 libgphoto2-port10 : Breaks: libgphoto2-port10:i386 (!= 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2.2) but 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libgphoto2-port10:i386 : Breaks: libgphoto2-port10 (!= 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2) but 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2.2 is installed.
 libxml2 : Breaks: libxml2:i386 (!= 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4 is to be installed.
 libxml2:i386 : Breaks: libxml2 (!= 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3 is installed.
 libudev1 : Breaks: libudev1:i386 (!= 204-5ubuntu20.3) but 204-5ubuntu20 is to be installed.
 libudev1:i386 : Breaks: libudev1 (!= 204-5ubuntu20) but 204-5ubuntu20.3 is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (!= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1) but 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 is to be installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx (!= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1 is installed.
 libsane : Breaks: libsane:i386 (!= 1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1) but 1.0.23-3ubuntu3 is to be installed.
 libsane:i386 : Breaks: libsane (!= 1.0.23-3ubuntu3) but 1.0.23-3ubuntu3.1 is installed.
 libosmesa6 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1 is installed.
 libgphoto2-6 : Breaks: libgphoto2-6:i386 (!= 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2.2) but 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libgphoto2-6:i386 : Breaks: libgphoto2-6 (!= 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2) but 2.5.3.1-1ubuntu2.2 is installed.
 libgnutls26 : Breaks: libgnutls26:i386 (!= 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1) but 2.12.23-12ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libgnutls26:i386 : Breaks: libgnutls26 (!= 2.12.23-12ubuntu2) but 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1 is installed.
 libjbig0 : Breaks: libjbig0:i386 (!= 2.0-2ubuntu4.1) but 2.0-2ubuntu4 is to be installed.
 libjbig0:i386 : Breaks: libjbig0 (!= 2.0-2ubuntu4) but 2.0-2ubuntu4.1 is installed.
 libelf1 : Breaks: libelf1:i386 (!= 0.158-0ubuntu5.1) but 0.158-0ubuntu5 is to be installed.
 libelf1:i386 : Breaks: libelf1 (!= 0.158-0ubuntu5) but 0.158-0ubuntu5.1 is installed.
 samba-vfs-modules : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is installed.
 libtasn1-6 : Breaks: libtasn1-6:i386 (!= 3.4-3ubuntu0.1) but 3.4-3 is to be installed.
 libtasn1-6:i386 : Breaks: libtasn1-6 (!= 3.4-3) but 3.4-3ubuntu0.1 is installed.
open: 90; closed: 2723; defer: 30; conflict: 45                                OThe following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:                     
1)      libasound2-plugins:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
2)      libavahi-client3:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
3)      libcgmanager0:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
4)      libcups2:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
5)      libdbus-1-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
6)      libelf1:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
7)      libfontconfig1:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
8)      libfreetype6:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
9)      libgd3:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
10)     libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 [Not Installed]                                    
11)     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [Not Installed]                                    
12)     libglapi-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
13)     libglib2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
14)     libglu1-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
15)     libgnutls26:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
16)     libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
17)     libgphoto2-port10:i386 [Not Installed]                                  
18)     libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 [Not Installed]                    
19)     libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
20)     libjbig0:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
21)     libjson-c2:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
22)     libldap-2.4-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
23)     libnih-dbus1:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
24)     libosmesa6 [Not Installed]                                              
25)     libosmesa6:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
26)     libpulse0:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
27)     libsane:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
28)     libsane-common:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
29)     libsasl2-modules:i386 [Not Installed]                                   
30)     libselinux1:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
31)     libsm6:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
32)     libssl1.0.0:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
33)     libtasn1-6:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
34)     libtiff5:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
35)     libudev1:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
36)     libusb-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
37)     libuuid1:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
38)     libxml2:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
39)     libxslt1.1:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
40)     libxt6:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
41)     p11-kit-modules:i386 [Not Installed]                                    
42)     samba [Not Installed]                                                   
43)     samba-dsdb-modules [Not Installed]                                      
44)     samba-vfs-modules [Not Installed]                                       
45)     winbind [Not Installed]                                                 
46)     wine [Not Installed]                                                    
47)     wine1.6 [Not Installed]                                                 
48)     wine1.6-amd64 [Not Installed]                                           
49)     wine1.6-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                                       

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                              
50)     wine1.6 recommends winbind                                              
51)     wine1.6-amd64 recommends libosmesa6                                     
52)     winetricks recommends wine                                              
53)     libsasl2-2:i386 recommends libsasl2-modules:i386 (>= 2.1.25.dfsg1-17buil
54)     libopenal1:i386 recommends libpulse0:i386 (>= 1:0.99.1)                 
55)     wine1.6-i386:i386 recommends libfontconfig1:i386 | libfontconfig:i386   
56)     wine1.6-i386:i386 recommends libsane:i386                               


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: posting the long list so we can have a look at it?  Without the list we would just be guessing, not answering!  ;-)

Comment: Hi Fabby,I cannot copy what the synaptic package manager says. Ubuntu software center's message is the following:
Synaptic PM list about everything under "To Be remoced" :))
Like firefox, gstreamer, compiz, account plugins, brasero, winff..... It is unbelievable but it really wants to kill them all :)

Comment: We need the full output. Can you try installing wine from the terminal and then [edit] your question to include the output? Thanks!

Comment: Open up Software & Updates > Updates tab. Make sure that the first 2 are enabled, ie. trusty-security & trusty-updates. Don't have trusty-proposed enabled. Then update your sources & try again. `sudo apt-get install wine` should install 1.6, `sudo apt-get install wine1.7` should install 1.7

Comment: Your issue was likely that you had installed some packages from trusty -proposed before. Then the proposed repo was disabled. Now wine can't install because some deps need package versions that are still in -proposed. This probably centers around winbind & samba. This question should not of been duped..

Comment: Thanks Lord for sending Mr. Doug here with the right answer! :)
Mr. Doug, god bless you. I am really greatful, that after all the efforts we have done, you came up with the right solution. :)
What should I do next? How can I mark this issue as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this without success.
The Terminal says:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Could you give the entire output, please?  Edit your question to reflect the full output.

Comment: Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Did you meant the above by "entire output"

Comment: @Hargitay : please add the error in the question by **editing** it.

Comment: Sorry guys for wasting your time! I am too dumb to edit the error. I don't Know, how to do that.
Although I really like 14.04 I think I will go back to 12.04. None of the Ubuntus after version 12.04 can recognize my USB phone. 
I asked this question earlier, but no one could answer it.
I love Ubuntu I prefer it to windows, but it is impossible to get rid of Windows completely :)
Have a nice day! Thank you for all you efforts! God bless all of you!
Attila

Comment: Could any of the essentials cause the problems mentioned here?

http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr